# How can I import a column from one sheet into another sheet of the same Google Sheets spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, importrange

I don't look for [ImportRange](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en) because I want to stay within the same Google Sheets spreadsheet. Instead, I want to import a column from one sheet into a column of another sheet within the same spreadsheet.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

One way to do this is with [ArrayFormula](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275). If the sheet you want to import from is named `Sheet1` and you want to select the entirety of `column A`, you can do the following:

```
=ArrayFormula('Sheet1'!A:A)
```

You can see an example of this in action here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kJraNDzrLF8-W_BxbL8pU6e_QuoMqFcl_sgyzT14L2Y/edit?usp=sharing

In general, you can use the form `[SheetName]![Range]` to pull in data from another sheet from within the same spreadsheet. In this case, ArrayFormula is needed to expand the entire range instead of just importing the first cell in the range.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Now the question is how to import the range with conditional formating?

Answer (score 5):

Also possible:

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!A:A)
```

Answer (score 0):

> I don't look for =ImportRange because I want to stay within the same Google Sheets spreadsheet.

seems to me to be repetition of a misconception I think I have seen elsewhere. [IMPORTRANGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340) works to fetch data from the same document or even the same sheet.

It may not be the *best* solution is all cases, but it is functional. For example:

```
=importrange(" k e y ","Sheet1!A:A")
```

will copy `ColumnA` to any other chosen (available) column even when `Sheet1` is the only sheet in the document. However authorisation is still required.

A possible use case is where reference to the column on the extreme left is to be maintained even after insertion of a new `ColumnA`. (In the formula `Sheet1!A:A` does not auto adjust when a column is inserted on the extreme left, it remains `Sheet1!A:A`.)

Comment: This is true, but with this solution one needs to know and take care about each document's key. In case you work with multiple (or even many) documents, it becomes a burden. 
After all - I shoudln't really care what is the current ID of the current document, since I'm already on it.
It would become a better solution, with an easily accessible reference to sheet's own ID.

Answer (score 0):

Suboptimal, but also possible:

`=TRANSPOSE(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A:A))`